# PHP Receiving XML

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have a small PHP script that is listening for a POST request.  I'm expecting xml, always.
Normally I'm the guy sending the xml requests.  But today I'm on the receiving side.

I figured it would be a simple case of listening for a $_POST, but I guess I may be incorrect - I'm getting nothing.

Here's my script that waits for anything xml:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    mail("me@myemail.com","some title i want", print_r($_POST, true)); 
}else{
    die("uh, what happened?");
}
?>
```

And here is a simple xml string I'm sending from another place:

```
<?php
$xml_data ='
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don\'t forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
';

function sendXML2Server($URL,$XML){
    $xml_data = trim($XML);
    $ch = curl_init($URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

echo sendXML2Server('https://someurl.com/inboundxml.php',$xml_data)
?>
```

And here's what I get in my email:

**Array
(
)**

I'm guessing I'm not working with an array correctly, but maybe there's something else I'm missing in all this.  I'm expecting to get back the actual xml string.

Comment: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS should be an associative array. You are setting it as a string and then trying to parse it as an array.

Comment: is the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER not necessary, in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sending nothing but data, thats why PHP cannot interpreter this data as some key&value. So, you need to send it as a value of variable:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml_data' => $xml_data));
```

or receive as a raw post data:

```
<?php
if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
    mail("me@myemail.com","some title i want", print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true)); 
}else{
    die("uh, what happened?");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS requires an array:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('content'=>$xml_data));`

Then retrieve it like:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset($_POST['content'])) {
    mail("me@myemail.com","some title i want", print_r($_POST['content'], true)); 
}else{
    die("uh, what happened?");
}
?>
```